# Why isn't my Android boot receiver working?

Tags: android, service, android-service, boot

I am developing a small android application in which I wanted to start some service once the device boot is completed.

This is the code I used to try to accomplish this, but it not receiving boot complete event, so it isn't working.

```
//in manifest file 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

//my schedule receiver 
public class MyScheduleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
      {
         Log.i("*************************TEST", "Service loaded at start");
         Toast.makeText(context, "device started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
}
```

`MyScheduleReceiver` never gets triggered; am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Comment: Try to add your package path before "MyScheduleReceiver" in your manifest. Like <receiver android:name="com.example.me.MyScheduleReceiver">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss a dot before MyScheduleReceiver

```
<receiver android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```